# how can we resize a row in dojo grid

Tags: javascript, dojo

I want to resize the dojo grid row by dragging it as we can do with the column.
I want it some thing like Excel row which we can resize(minimize or maximize its height), is there a way to do this in dojo grid?

Thanks
Faz

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to say that there isn't a solution for this in the dojo grid right now.

Comment: @AndréSchild Why does not provide an answer? Imagine a question about [¿How to Square a circle?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squaring_the_circle), What would be the answer?